# Data is lost while extracting data from xls

Tags: excel, go, xls

i have 12000 rows data in xls file, i want to read  parse, and insert those data to database. I use [extrame/xls](https://github.com/extrame/xls/)  library to read xls data,
but some data are different/lost from the actual data from excel.

this is my readXlsFile method :

```
func readXLSFile(filename string) ([][]string, error) {
    result := [][]string{}

    log.Println("Get into readXlsFile")

    xlFile, err := xls.Open(filename, "utf-8")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    sheet1 := xlFile.GetSheet(0)
    str := ""
    //log.Println("Max Row ", int(sheet1.MaxRow))
    for i := 0; i <= (int(sheet1.MaxRow)); i++ {
        row1 := sheet1.Row(i)
        temp := []string{}
        for j := 0; j <= int(row1.LastCol()); j++ {
            temp = append(temp, row1.Col(j))

            //log.Println("Max Col", int(row1.LastCol()), "Of row ", i+1)
            str += fmt.Sprintf("column %d data = %s ", j+1, row1.Col(j))
        }
        log.Printf("row %d data : %s \n", i+1, str)
        str = ""
        result = append(result, temp)
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

and here is my log that show the different data from my xls file :

```
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1836 data : column 1 data = :61:171218C59000NMSC column 2 data =   
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1837 data : column 1 data = :86: column 2 data =  column 3 data =  column 4 data =  column 5 data =  column 6 data =  column 7 data =  column 8 data =  column 9 data =  column 10 data =  column 11 data =  column 12 data = PLS10299 column 13 data =  column 14 data = 22162- column 15 data =   
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1838 data : column 1 data = :61:171218D300NMSC column 2 data =   
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1839 data : column 1 data = :86: column 2 data =  column 3 data =  column 4 data =  column 5 data =  column 6 data =  column 7 data =  column 8 data =  column 9 data =  column 10 data =  column 11 data =  column 12 data = PLS10299 column 13 data =  column 14 data = 22162- column 15 data =   
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1840 data : column 1 data = :61:171218D700NMSC column 2 data =   
2018/03/12 19:24:24 service.inquiry.go:4557: row 1841 data : column 1 data = :86: column 2 data =  column 3 data =  column 4 data =  column 5 data =  column 6 data =  column 7 data =  column 8 data =  column 9 data =  column 10 data =  column 11 data =  column 12 data = PLS10299 column 13 data =  column 14 data = 22162- column 15 data =
```

and this is the actual data from xls file : 
[image]

does anybody know why is this happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: When you say "some data", does this mean that most of the rows are OK and only a few appear to glitch, or that the problem is systemic and manifests itself for all the rows? I speculate the issue may be due to the fact it's too easy in Excel to input badly structured data which *appears to look* okay due to the WYSIWYG nature of this application.

Comment: BTW a simple approach to prove/disprove my claim is to open the offending document in Excel and export the contents of its first sheet as a CVS stream, and then look what's there—is the data in it "corrupt" in the same way you observe with your Go code, or not.

Comment: thank your for responding my question,
i already check the uploaded excel and original exel file, its the same.
and i forgot to mention, this thing happen only on my machine test, its works fine at my local computer/laptop. my laptop already have the same library version, and go version. idk what causing this problem to be happen.

Comment: Study the source code of that package to see whether it parses the documents naturally or calls out to Excel (via COM/COM+). If it does the latter, the difference could be explained by the difference of Excel versions. Otherwise you'll need to experiment further like copying the "working" binary to the "faulty" machine and trying there. Oh, and by the way, do you have architectural differences between those two machines—like 32 vs 64 bit?

Comment: i'll try to read the code of the package. both has the same architecture x86_64,
do you have any idea to populate this bug on my local laptop?
it'll be much easier for me to search the root cause.